# What is the mechanism for the oxidation of benzene to maleic anhydride using vanadium pentoxide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What is the mechanism for the oxidation of benzene to maleic anhydride using vanadium pentoxide, $\ce{V2O5}$?

Answer (score 6):

A talk given by Ken Waugh named *The Detailed Kinetics of the Partial Oxidation Reactions: Benzene/Butane to Maleic Anhydride, Ethylene to Ethylene Oxide,*<sup>[1]</sup> proposes the following mechanism on page 4:

[image: DA Dowden mechanism of benzene oxidation to MA using molecularly adsorbed oxygen]

[1]: Acessible as pdf via [rsc.org](http://www.rsc.org/images/Ken_Waugh_tcm18-236914.pdf)