# Benzene to phenol in a single step

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, phenols

My teacher told me we can convert benzene to phenol within a single step using $\ce{V2O5}$/ $\ce{O2}$ at 300 ⁰C (**not 500 ⁰C**). Later I searched for that reaction but I couldn't find it in all over Google except in Allen's Chemistry handbook.

Does that reaction really occur and if it occurs then what is the mechanism of that reaction?

[image]

Comment: I don’t think that we can get phenol from benzene just by $\ce{V_2O_5}$. As you know, $\ce{V_2O_5}$ is an oxidising agent, it will oxidise our benzene.

Comment: Related(for the maleic anhydride case): https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8209/what-is-the-mechanism-for-the-oxidation-of-benzene-to-maleic-anhydride-using-van

Comment: Also related: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/i200015a003

Comment: TL; DR: Not exactly ratta maar, a mechanisms is there.. Perhaps it maybe beyond your current level of understanding,or tour teacher is unaware of the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terminology given to that reaction by your instructors is very odd. But the more important thing is that $\ce{V_2O_5}$ isn't a reagent in converting benzene directly to phenol, rather it is a catalyst. The first few pages of the book linked by @M.Farooq writes

> [...] Various sources have reported the use of nitrous oxide to supply the active oxygen [1-8]. Iwamoto et al. appear to be the pioneers in the early 1980s, where they employed $\ce{N_2O}$ over a **$\ce{V_2O_5 - SiO_2}$ catalyst** and reported a benzene conversion of $11\%$ and a phenol selectivity of $45\%$.

And even in this [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1003995311603940) it is written about vanadium oxides that

> These materials have been tested in the hydroxylation of benzene to phenol in liquid-phase with molecular oxygen in the absence of reductant. The catalyst exhibits high selectivity for phenol (61%) at benzene conversion of 4.6%, which is a relatively good result in comparison with other studies employing molecular oxygen as the oxidant.

So, you notice the oxygen for phenol comes from either from $\ce{N_2O}$ or molecular oxygen itself, while $\ce{V_2O_5}$ is just a catalyst. But in your original post you have written

> My teacher told me we can convert benzene to phenol within a single step via Ratta Maar Reaction using $\ce{V_2O_5}$.

There is no mention of nitrous oxide or molecular oxygen (although in images you do have molecular oxygen). So, the gist is that your instructors told you something but didn't care to explain the intricacies and complexity of conversion.

Answer (score 18):

The reaction of benzene over $\ce{V2O5/ PtAu}$ catalyst at lower temperatures, can convert benzene  to phenol with some success.

See this book here [Direct hydroxylation of benzene](https://books.google.com/books?id=YQjHiursJ80C&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=benzene%20to%20phenol%20V2O5&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

[The original question before editing was: What is the Ratta Maar Reaction?] Someone has played a prank with you with the named reaction. "Ratta maar" is a slang for "rote memorization" in Hindi/Urdu, which implies keep on memorizing without understanding and perhaps this is what your teacher wanted too. I assume this Allen's Chemistry Handbook is being taught or used in India.

Comment: Allen is a coaching institute for the JEE exams... You'll find many such "unexplained" phenomena in the coaching manuals. Half of the traffic on SE is due to these questions caused by loose ends which were not explained fully, because they won't ask the reason in the exam.

Comment: @Micelle Yeah,I know about Allen and such related cram schools(once prepared for such exams myself). And sadly,your point is very true; this reaction does have a mechanism as I have higlighted in the comments above,but if the teacher doesn't know it or isn't willing to teach it,he proclaims it as ratta maar. This creates a false impression about the nature of chemistry in high school students, and hence there questions are highly downvoted on SE. It's painful to watch as there questions receive negative ratings and are closed ultimately :(

Comment: @Mr. Yusuf ; on my online video lecture my organic chemistry teacher told that we can convert benzene to phenol by using O2/V2O5 at 300⁰C which called ' RMR ' and he told its full name as Ratta Maar Reaction. Whatsever, we had not asked him anything he was just teaching the theory . So there is no cause to use any slang . You should not abuse any educator or any coaching centre like that.

Comment: @zombie, I am sorry but the coaching centers, the way they make the students cram for exams are curse in the education system. These systems can never create original thinkers. The same college teachers who are unable to teach in a govt. college become perfect instructors in coaching centers. Not all coaching centers are like that but a majority it.

Comment: @YusufHasan, If you are interested in why chemistry never attracts the best and the brightest, you should read "Chemistry: Fact or Fiction" by Gillespie from 1970s-yes the same person who came up with VSEPR theory. Despite being a 50 year article, the facts remain true today.

Comment: @zombie You didn't get my point. I haven't used any slang; he did as he gave the reaction a made-up name RMR. Moreover,it is the duty of the teacher to teach the mechanism of the reaction along with the reaction equation(if a mechanism exists). If he doesn't do so, atleast he or she should state outright that a mechanistic pathway exists for this reaction,but we won't be covering it here. Stating a reaction outright as "Ratta Maar" (meaning rote memorization) when studies on mechanisms have been done is both incorrect as well as undermining to the scientists who have worked on the research....

Comment: .... I am not abusing anyone,just stating what should have been the way to handle this situation

Comment: @M. Farooq Ok,will definitely give it a whirl :)

Comment: I agree with @M.Farooq, IIT JEE is a kind of smudge in the education system that needs to be stained off. No exam will ever want a student to memorise 50-100 without even knowing “where can we find vanadium for making $\ce{V_2O_5}$?”.

Comment: @M.Farooq Can't find a link to the aforementioned work; can you provide me a source for "Chemistry: Fact or Fiction"?

Comment: @YusufHasan, You are right, I cannot locate an online copy of his article. I had a scanned copy shared by a professor. The full citation is Gillespie, Ronald. "Chemistry–fact or fiction? Some reflections on the teaching of chemistry." Chemistry Canada 28.11 (1976): 23-8.

Comment: Note that the question has been edited to remove the reference to "Ratta Maar Reaction", just in case some readers are wondering why this answer mentioned it.